# Problemas com Opencv no Qt creator

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv

Programa não apresenta nenhum erro ao dar build, mas quando executo o código ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> libopencv_core.so.3.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**o arquivo .pro esta assim:**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Pixel_manipulation
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
LIBS += -lopencv_imgcodecs
LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d
LIBS += -lz
```

**O codigo que tento executar:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
 QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
Mat image;
image = imread("bolhas.jpeg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("imagem",image);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**Estou utilizando o Ubuntu 14.04 e Opencv 3.3**

Comment: Tentou [linkar estaticamente](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) a biblioteca?

Comment: Tentei e não resolveu tambem!

Comment: Aparentemente você adicionou a pasta errada `INCLUDEPATH`, você disse estar usando o Opencv 3.3, mas a pasta apontada é a "2",  e no libs deveria ser `LIBS += \`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs\``